# Trouble hosting SQL Server database via Plesk panel

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, hosting, plesk

First I give information about my products subscription, I have one year "Ultimate" subscription for Windows hosting with Plesk in addition I have subscribed for one year of SiteLock. I am trying to host ASP.NET websites with SQL Server databases, I am having hard time doing so. Firstly via the Plesk panel I did the following:

1. I created SQL Server database, then I tried to upload `.bak` version of my database but unfortunately I got the msg: the feature currently unavailable.

   [unavailable feature for MS database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCTwv.png)
2. I created a new database user for my database created in step 1, I connected my SQL Server Management Studio and then tried to create or import databases, but unfortunately the user has no admin permission. The users Plesk panel allow you to create user which has only limited permission for viewing the databases only.

   [permission denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCTwv.png)

Is there a way to create admin user for my SQL Server database via Plesk control panel? Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe because of new 12.5 default permissions, check `Tools&Settings > Database Hosting Settings`:

[image: plesk ms sql server alter databasepermissions]