# Can't create new database user with full access in plesk 12.5

Tags: database, sql-server-2012, plesk, privileges

I'm trying to create a user for my sql server database in plesk 12.5 web panel but when I create a user, this user has limited role.
I can't change user privileges even though T-sql...
for example when I tried to copy one of my databases that is on another server to this server using Management Studio, I get this error in image below:
[SSMS Database Copy Wizard Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMYnh.jpg)

I want to create a user with owner role and full access...

this is my plesk options for ceating new database user:[Plesk Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoadO.jpg)

I'm so confused that what's going on here!
in earlier versions of plesk I didn't face this issue...
any suggestion?

Comment: Plesk check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37132926/1592008

Comment: @OlegNeumyvakin as you can see in the image in my post, I don't have that option(Tools&Setting that you mentioned in your answer) in my plesk control panel...

Comment: oh, I see. Are you logging in Plesk as admin?

Comment: yes...I'm logging as admin...there is just one username & password that my host provider gave me & I'm using this account & this must be the admin account of my plesk...am I wrong?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask your hosting provider to switch on option

"Grant the ALTER DATABASE permission to all Microsoft SQL database users"

in Tools&Settings > Database Hosting Settings

or if you have access to RDP you can execute following command:

```
plesk sbin server_pref -u -grant-alter-database-to-mssql-users true
```

Comment: You saved me, man...I asked my host provider & they activated the Grant option & now my database user is db_owner...tnx again...